# Object manipulation by using stringify, regex and parse

Tags: javascript

I'm currently reviewing code for a large pull request made by a new developer. This individual has what I believe is a very unconventional way of editing javascript objects - he uses `JSON.stringify()`, followed by using `string.replace()` on the resulting string to update both keys and values, and then uses `JSON.parse()` to convert back to a JS object. I'm pretty sure this is a very bad practice, but I'm struggling to explain exactly why this is the case. Am I wrong here, is this an acceptable way to write code? If not, how do I explain this to my new colleague?

Comment: One big reason: it's easier using JS methods. Another: JSON stringify doesn't serialise everything `JSON.stringify({ func: () => 'hi' }) => '{}'`

Comment: `JSON.stringify` removes keys which are undefined, functions and all the inherited methods, converts Date object to string which doesn't get parsed back etc. The `.replace` call is highly unreliable too. If you have `{ a: { a: "value" } }`, and you try to match the `a` key, it won't know which to match. Ask them if there is a reason they are not using `obj.key = 'newValue'`

Answer (score 1):

Well for one thing, it's an overly round about way to go about it, there are built-in JavaScript methods that can do what he's doing more efficiently.

You can also count readability as an issue if you're working in a group and it can make your code inconsistent. Both are pretty bad imo.